# Is it possible to change the system date for php (only)

Tags: php

Is it possible to change the system date for php (only). 
I want this for debugging/testing purpose.

```
//Test 1  (2010-01-01)
$datetime = new DateTime(); //(2010-01-01)

//Test 2  (2010-02-01)
$datetime = new DateTime(); //(2010-02-01)
```

I can't really change the real system clock, because other developers are working on the same system (well I could but still).
I'm just hoping this is possible, or that someone knows a nice trick.

When I print the phpinfo(); I see the following line:

```
Timezone Database   internal
```

Maybe it's changeable to something like "manual" and ad a timezone with +120

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good use case for using virtual machines for each developer…

Comment: Yep true, but that isn't the case right now =)

Comment: So, you were asking, if its possible, as I am telling you in my answer, the answer is NO, its not possible in a way, you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an encapsulation issue -- why not search for all mentions of date() or time() and replace them with $site->getDisplayedDate(), or something else appropriate to your code?

I feel your pain, but I don't think there's any way to do this. Think about it this way... how would you feel if, in some unrelated code, you called time() and it gave you some date 3 weeks in the future?

You can change only timezone (and ofcourse only couple hours forward / backward; and not whole day forward), but thats not correct solution...

Comment: The code is good, there are no issues so i don't see a reason to change it. 
It's really for testing purpose and "flying" through time, so i can refresh my page and the date is 1 month further

I was thinking about changing the timezone to +120 hours

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own `DateTime` class that extends the default `DateTime` and hence change the behaviour:

```
<?php
    class CustomDateTimeVariables {
        public static $date = 'now';
    }

    class CustomDateTime extends DateTime {
        public function __construct($time = null, DateTimeZone $timezone = null) {
            if ($time === null) {   
                $time = CustomDateTimeVariables::$date;
            }
            if ($timezone !== null) {
                parent::__construct($time, $timezone);
            } else {
                parent::__construct($time);
            }
        }
    }

    CustomDateTimeVariables::$date = '2010-01-01';
    $datetime1 = new CustomDateTime();

    CustomDateTimeVariables::$date = '2010-01-02';
    $datetime2 = new CustomDateTime();

    var_dump($datetime1->Format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //"2010-01-01 00:00:00"
    var_dump($datetime2->Format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //"2010-01-02 00:00:00"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/jyPW0lJP)

This way you can also set the default time very easily (check `CustomDateTimeVariables`):

```
<?php
    class CustomDateTimeVariables {
        public static $date = 'now +120 hours';
    }

    class CustomDateTime extends DateTime {
        public function __construct($time = null, DateTimeZone $timezone = null) {
            if ($time === null) {   
                $time = CustomDateTimeVariables::$date;
            }
            if ($timezone !== null) {
                parent::__construct($time, $timezone);
            } else {
                parent::__construct($time);
            }
        }
    }

    $datetime = new CustomDateTime();

    var_dump($datetime->Format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //"2013-10-29 13:37:39"
?>
```

*..and when it goes live, you can simply change the default back to `now`.*

Comment: That is possible, but I think it isn't a nice solution. Because it requires to alter all the places where DateTime is used for testing functionality

Comment: @SanderVisser I agree with you - there isn't really a "pretty" way, but this way is the only one that can be fixed with a simple bulk "find/replace" in all the code.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to change the timezone database. something like
add_timezone("Debug/Zone1", "+1200");